# double casting in c

Tags: c, casting

I have gone over [this code](http://cs.usfca.edu/~cruse/cs635s03/pgfaults.c) and I have noticed this casting that looks weird

```
oldidt = (unsigned long long *)(*(unsigned long*)(oldidtr+1));
```

To me it looks like the first cast is affecting the `+1` so it will move 4 bytes (a pointer), and the second cast is for the result being an `unsigned long long *`. And the star in the outer shell on the inner cast is an "access this memory" star.

- Is that right?
- Why bother if the original definition was a pointer, and we're casting to another pointer, the `+1` will still be a 4 byte jump.
- What would happen if I write instead `oldidt = *(oldidt+1);`? (Assuming the compiler doesn't complain, and gives out and exec)

The declaration of `oldidt` was:

```
static unsigned long long *oldidt;
```

I'm calling the casts "first" and "second" according to invocation (left is the second).

Comment: The +1 increment will be done in terms of whatever type of pointer `oldidtr` is (apparently `unsigned short`).  (The surrounding parentheses prevent any possible interaction with the cast.)  The result is then cast to an `unsigned long*` and the value at that location is accessed with `*`.  That fetched value (presumably two shorts combined) is then cast to an `unsigned long long` and stored in oldidt.

Comment: Oops, the result is cast to a *pointer* to `unsigned long long`.

Comment: (And, no, it doesn't make any sense.  But this is kernel code, after all.  Often nonsensical things are done.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this code is using several `unsigned short int`s to store pointers in two halves. This assumes that an `unsigned short int` is half as wide as a pointer. The code is extracting the stored pointer from two adjacent shorts, namely the second and third member of an array, and interpreting it as a pointer to an `unsigned long long int`.

So, the final cast is necessary to reinterpret an integer as a pointer, while the first (inner) cast serves to read a differently typed value from an existing variable, namely a long from a short (or rather, from two adjacent shorts).

Comment: oldidtr is a short pointer: `static unsigned short oldidtr[3]`

Comment: Why a person would possibly need to do that ? In assembly it's common to "compress" as much data as possible inside a "word" of a given size depending on the target machine; what is the point of doing this in C for the pointers ?

Comment: @user2485710 - There's no difference between C and assembler re the need to "compress" -- it would be done to achieve system control blocks consistent with some allocation scheme, prior designs, etc.

Comment: @user2485710 - Where what?

Comment: @HotLicks nevermind, it was a reply to your comment before the edit. But still, what is the use of that ?

Comment: @user2485710 - The use of what?  The layout of Linux control blocks was defined about 20 years ago.  This was when RAM was smaller, pointers were smaller, etc.  Some has been changed over the years, but some not, in order to main compatibility between versions.

Comment: @HotLicks the use of doing this dance just to store a pointer, but now I get an idea about why this is there . Thanks.

Comment: @user2485710 - As to why they're doing that particular bit of monkey business, I haven't a clue.  I suppose one could study it for a few days and figure it out, but we all have better things to do than that.

Comment: For those wondering about the layout of the `oldidtr[]` array - it's defined to match the requirements of the CPU's `sidt` and `lidt` instructions, which store/load the CPU's interrupt descriptor table register. The format used by the CPU is a 16-bit limit followed by a 32-bit base address. I suppose a struct could have been used, but then there would be cruft needed to prevent padding being generated. It was probably six of one, half dozen of the other as far as choosing between the ugly cast or getting a proper struct declared.